# Very rapid clicking on pedals

Tags: pedals, clicking

I purchased a brand new Raleigh Overtake hybrid bicycle last week. On my fourth ride, the pedals started clicking loudly and rapidly, not unlike the sound of winding an alarm clock. It only makes the sound when I'm sitting on it and pedaling. It occurs when pedaling in all gears, and seems to make the least noise when I'm pedaling really hard or pedaling VERY lightly. There's absolutely no feeling to the noise, it's simply a noise. I can't examine exactly where the sound emanates from because it doesn't make the sound unless I'm actually riding it. Turning the pedals by hand doesn't produce the sound.

The store will make any adjustments within 30 days of purchase, but I've already had to adjust the rear brakes and tightness of the front wheel myself, so I don't have much confidence in their abilities (it's a large chain hardware store).

Comment: If its brand new, its a warranty problem.  Don't mess with it yourself or it may void the warranty.

Comment: You can try setting up a camera, either on a stand or ask an assistant.  This works very well if you have access to Rollers - ask around and see if you can borrow some ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: The last time I had a constant click / ticking noise when peddling it turned out to be one my shoe laces hitting the arm on the downstroke. Took a while to find the issue, was just by chance I tried rotating the crank by hand to find out.

Comment: That's hilarious! But no, it's not my laces. I tuck my laces into my shoes when I ride. This sounds almost like someone winding an alarm clock.

Comment: So I took it to the store from which I bought it. I explained to the guy what the problem was. He worked on it for half an hour, then I took it for a spin around the parking lot, and it still clicked. He then said "Well, some bikes are just noisy." So I rode around for about an hour, and I put heavy equal pressure on both pedals when I was coasting. And the clicking went away. No sound for 20-30 minutes, and it's still good. So maybe he or I fixed it.

Comment: I had this sort of problem very recently.  I heard a clicking noise with every pedal stroke, but only when I was riding the bike, never when I got off and tried to replicate it on the stand.  Turns out that it was caused by me replacing the pedals and failing to grease the new ones.  I'd take off the pedals, get some really goopy grease, and lather it on the pedal threads, put them back on and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: I've had a similar problem for a while, rapid creaking/clicking. It disappeared completely after I cleaned the bushing/nut of the pedal and greased it. I never really figured out why, but I suspect it was just pebbles or dirt.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sitting on it and pedaling

Does that mean it doesn't click when you're standing on it and pedaling?

In that case, I'd grease the seatpost and ensure it's tight. If it's a seatpost which has a separate non-integral head, in that case you might even consider changing the seatpost.

If it clicks even when pedaling standing, you might want to check the bottom bracket, cranks and pedals are tightly attached. Remember to put grease on any metal-to-metal contact surface after taking it apart before reinstalling. Some of these jobs might require special bicycle specific tools.

> Turning the pedals by hand doesn't produce the sound.

That's to be expected. Unless you're riding the bike at significant speed or at significant uphill, there's no resistance to pedaling and thus the forces are very small.

Comment: Standing and pedaling makes the sound. Sitting and pedaling makes the sound. Strangely enough, the sound diminishes a lot when I'm pushing really hard. It's at its worst when pedaling at regular intensity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Clicks and creaks can be difficult to diagnose, partly because sound or vibration travels along the frame tubes so seems to be coming from somewhere else. I'd check everything was properly greased and tightened starting at the bottom bracket, then cranks, pedal threads (these three because riding with them loose can cause costly damage) then pedal bearings, pedal cages or mechanisms, chain-ring bolts. While all the time being mindful that it could be something as obscure as the handlebar stem or saddle frame or cassette lock-ring, or a loose cable end snagging something.